# Notify $email_address of any new answers like stackoverflow

Tags: php, wordpress, notify, subscribe

I work on a theme that allows Registered Users to post on a Wordpress Blog, I created a form (title, category, entry).

The question is, how can I add a new checkbox "Notify me when new answer is posted"? I need a function, not a plugin.

Here is the function that handles the question posting:

function post_new_question($question_title, $question_content, $question_category) {

```
 $question_title_stripped = strip_tags($question_title);
 $question_content_stripped = strip_tags($question_content);

 $user = wp_get_current_user();

 global $wpdb;
 $gather_questions = "SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_author = '" . $user->ID . "'";
 $user_questions = $wpdb->get_results($gather_questions);

 if (isEmptyString($question_title_stripped)) return new WP_Error('no_title_entered', 'Enter a title for your quesion');
 if (isEmptyString($question_content_stripped)) return new WP_Error('no_content', 'Enter a breif description for your quesion');

 foreach ($user_questions as $user_question) {
  if ($user_question->post_author == $user->ID ) {
   if ($user_question->post_title == $question_title_stripped) {
    return new WP_Error('duplicate_user_question', 'You have already asked this exact question.');
   } else {}   
  } else {}
 }

 $question_author = $user->ID;

 $post = array(
   'ID' => '',
   'post_author' => $question_author, 
   'post_category' => array($question_category),
   'post_content' => $question_content_stripped, 
   'post_title' => $question_title_stripped,
   'post_status' => 'publish'
 );  

 $question_id = wp_insert_post($post); }
```

PS: Usage of wp_email function would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so, here we go:

In the form where you the user add the post, I added

```
<input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="yes" name="notify" checked="checked" />
```

Then in the header

```
$notify = $_POST['notify'];
```

Now, in the function that handles the form and insert the post into wpdb

```
if ($notify) {
        $wpdb->insert('wp_notify', array('user_id' => $question_author, 'post_id' => $question->ID), array( '%d', '%d' ) );
    }
```

And the last thing, for the function that handles the comments, after the comment is added:

```
$notify = $wpdb->get_col("SELECT user_id FROM wp_notify WHERE user_id = {$wp_query->post->post_author} AND post_id = {$wp_query->post->ID}");

    foreach ($notify as $user) :
        if($user == $wp_query->post->post_author && $user != $user_ID) {
            wp_mail('email', 'New Answer on Post: asdasdasdas', 'google.ro');
        }
    endforeach;
```

And it works like a charm. Maybe someone find this useful.
Thanks **dirk** for your help.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to grab the `post_author` field from the database for that post. Look up the database record for that author/user, pull the email out of that record, and send an email with a notification of a new answer to that email address. The [`get_userdata`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_userdata) WordPress function will take a user ID (from the `post_author` field) and return an object with information about the user, including their email address.

```
global $post;
$user = get_userdata($post->post_author);
wp_mail($user->user_email, 'New Answer on Post: '.$post->post_title, get_permalink($post->ID));
```

That will grab the author of the current post and send them an email with the subject "New Answer on Post: [Name of Post]" and the message body being the URI for the post.

Comment: Thanks, but how to check if user checked if he want or not to be notified? And where does it look for new answer on that specific post?

Comment: For notifications you'll need to use either post meta or a custom table in the database to store that preference. You could use the comments system and have comments act as answers, then tie into the actions system to have a function executed when a new comment is posted that would check whether the user wanted to receive an email, and if they did send that email.

Comment: Well actually comments act like answers. I will make a new table, wp_notify and I will store user_id and post_id (if they wanted to be notified) right? But I need an example of how to check if new answer is posted on that entry. Thanks.

Comment: You would want to use a [WordPress action](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference#Comment.2C_Ping.2C_and_Trackback_Actions) for catching when a new comment is posted. The specific action is [comment_post](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/comment_post), I believe.